# How to use the forceResendingToken in firebase phone auth in flutter to resend the otp

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am looking for a way to resend the **OTP** in firebase verifyPhoneNumber in flutter.
I have gone through the [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/main.dart) about phoneAuth but could not find a way to resend OTP.
There is an option of forceResendingToken

```
final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      _smsCodeController.text = testSmsCode;
    };


await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: this._phone,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieval,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        forceResendingToken: ,//how to get this token
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 40),
        verificationCompleted: verifSuccessful,
        verificationFailed: verifFailed);
  }
```

How to use this token to resend the OTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Firebase reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider.html#verifyPhoneNumber(java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks,%20com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken)):

> the `ForceResendingToken` obtained from [`onCodeSent(String, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) callback`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks.html#onCodeSent(java.lang.String,%20com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken)) to force re-sending another verification SMS before the auto-retrieval timeout.

So in your case that'd be the [`PhoneCodeSent`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/PhoneCodeSent.html) callback of the [verifyPhoneNumber()](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html) call.

Answer (score 1):

You have to record the value of resendToken from the codesent callback and pass it to the forceresendingtoken. Also, the inbuilt timeout duration is 30 seconds So make sure you tap on resend button after timeout seconds, you may use timerbutton package it's very handy in this case.

Firebase sends 3x same SMS code and then change it to different.

```
String _verificationId = "";
int? _resendToken;

Future<bool> sendOTP({required String phone}) async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phone,
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
    _verificationId = verificationId;
    _resendToken = resendToken;
    },
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 25),
    forceResendingToken: _resendToken,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
    verificationId = _verificationId;
  },
 );
 debugPrint("_verificationId: $_verificationId");
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when resending the otp then am receiving the same otp everytime on resend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).